# extern const in this particular situation

Tags: c++, extern

There are other questions about using `extern` and `const` in C++. I also have read about internal and external linkage (it is been a while since I used C++) But I would appreciate if someone reminds to me about the usage of the following particular situation.

I have two `cpp` files:  Description.cpp and Register.cpp and one `hpp` file: Description. h .They are something like this

```
//Description.cpp
#include "Description.hpp"
extern const FD models[];
//some other code
```

.

```
//Register.cpp
#include "Description.hpp"
extern const FD models[2]={
                           {"elementA",{1,2}},
                           {"elementB",{3,4}}
                          };
```

.

```
//Description.hpp
struct FD{
  string name;
  double v[2];
};
```

I am wondering why the extern keyword is necessary in Register.cpp

Comment: It is not necessary. Try removing it. You should not get a linker error.

Comment: I read that consts are inherently *internally linked* , so in that case models would be availabe only to the translation unit Register, not to the Description one.

Comment: @M.M. The *header* doesn't mention `models`, only the type. The line `extern const FD models[];` is in a `.cpp` file, although it should probably be in a header.

Comment: @DanielH it would be good practice to have an extern declaration in the header

Comment: Have a look at this [Storage class specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: @DanaYan If a `const` object is `extern`, it only needs to be declared, not defined.

Comment: @M.M I completely agree, as I explained in the answer below, but that's not how the OP shows the code.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the comments, by default, a `const` object has [internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage), meaning you can only see it from the file you define it in. To change that, you use the keyword `extern`, which means "this variable can be seen from other files". Therefore, in `Register.cpp`, you need `extern` to tell the linker to make this visible elsewhere, and in `Description.cpp` you need `extern` to tell the compiler it might be defined elsewhere.

A better solution would be to move the declaration `extern const FD models[];` into a `.hpp` file (either `Description.hpp` or a new `Register.hpp`, depending on details of your project). Then in `Description.cpp` and any other code that uses `models`, you include that file and don't need the declaration at all. In `Register.cpp`, you also include this header. Then the compiler knows that `models` has external linkage and you don't need to say `extern` again.